# Link jquery file is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

my jquery file path is *c:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\assets\js\jquery.min.js*
..I have tried like below on my page but jquery file don't included ! What I am wrong ..

```
{{-- <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script> --}}
```

Comment: You're referencing assets twice! What i suggest you to do is place your jQuery in your ```public/js/``` folder and then reference like this: ```<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>``` because referencing it from your asset folder is really a bad practice. I don't mention about Elixir but you should read about it in Laravel docs! Assets in your host ONLY will be served if they are in your **public** directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `URL::asset()` is a helper function in laravel,
when you use this function it automatically generates the URL path to the 
ProjectName/public and you have to specify the remaining path inside the asset method.
So, first you would want to place the `css` , `js` , 'images' and 'fonts' files inside your public folder that is in the root directory of your project.
then you can use the `asset()` or `URL::asset()` to locate your file.
the standard folder structure looks like this ..
ProjectName/public/css/main.css
ProjectName/public/js/jquery.min.js

etc ..

i think that would work for you .

Answer (score 0):

Add those file in `public/` folder like `public/assets/js/jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have proper access rights to aforementioned resource (js file). You can also try to view the file with your web browser by visit http://your_hostname/assets/js/jquery.min.js